# How to justify the right alignment of tufte-book

Tags: margins, tufte, parskip, justification

For example I have this MWE with `tufte-book`,

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
%\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} 

\begin{document}

\noindent\kant[1]
\kant[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

*The class of this document does not provide for an alignment on the right like the one on the left?* And to prevent the indent in each paragraph, should I insert `\noindent` every time because `parkskip` package has no effect?

I'm using Papeeria, how could it be a minimum complete code with the justification on the left and right complete with captions and references on the right or on the left?

Comment: Unrelated: since latex has no hyphenation patterns for pseudo latin, it might be an idea to use the `kantlipsum` and its corresponding `\kant` command instead of `lipsum` and `\lipsum` and the sample text is now English

Comment: @daleif Thank you very much...now I edit my question....

Comment: Did you actually read the manual? Page 27, see the `justified` class option.

Comment: Among Tufte's beliefs is that ragged right is easier to read. So the classes based on E. Tufte's ideas use it by default (but offer options for justifying).

Comment: @daleif No, absolutely with a lot of sincerity :-(.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much for you precious support...I like this documentclass...and sometimes I like to change :-) the style...of my previous documents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As egreg mentions in a comment, Tufte feels that ragged right text is easier to read and thus that is the default for the `tufte-book` class. But the class offers the `justified` class option for those who want something else.

```
\documentclass[justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} 
\begin{document}
\noindent\kant[1]
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since many documents in this class are all unjustified, I thought this class had no justification. This also happens with captions, figures, right the justified alignment?

Comment: @Sebastiano no idea I don't use the class. I just answered the question you posed, nothing else

Comment: I had reduced everything to a minimum because I didn't install MikTeX on this pc and used Papeeria. https://www.papeeria.com/ I will wait :-)...always thank youuuuu..